# Office 365 Oauth web api

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365

we're currently using the office 365 api but we're a little bit stuck in the oauth process. On the target platform we have no access to a browser, which cause the main problem using the oauth procedure.

Does Microsoft offer other kinds of authentication like Limited Input Device Authentication like google does? Or are there any alternatives, when no browser is available?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to do it without a browser, depending on your scenario. If you're looking to prompt the user yourself for username/password, you can pass those directly via ADAL. For example, here's how to do it using the ADAL for Node.js: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/username-password-sample.js

The trick when you do this is that there must be user consent already recorded in Azure AD. Because this bypasses the user consent screen, it has to be "pre-consented". One way to do this is to have the organizational administrator register the application in their own Azure AD, which by default consents for all users in the org.

Another approach would be to use the [client credential flow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx). In this scenario, the administrator consents once for their entire organization, and the app then has access to all mailboxes in that org.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing it. I'll try the suggestion and eval what's most appropiate for our use case

Comment: thanks a lot Jason! We've built a small nodejs prototype and can now query the inbox of office 365 with your help!